# How to list people with a short explanation

Tags: punctuation, lists, appositives

> Andy, Bob, Christine, his girlfriend, Debby and I are going for dinner
>   tomorrow.

Christine is Bob's girlfriend. There are no other relations. There are five people altogether. **Is the quoted sentence correctly punctuated?**

It would be even more confusing if the adjacent name and explanation had the same gender:

> Andy, Bob, Chris, his brother, Debby and I are going for dinner tomorrow.

Is Chris Bob's brother or is the unnamed brother of Chris joining dinner? **How to avoid the ambiguity here?**

(I am aware of a [related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/312613/how-to-list-a-small-group-of-people-with-short-descriptions) but semicolons seem to be overkill here.)

Comment: Who is Debby's boyfriend in this list?

Comment: Chris and his brother, Debby, Andy, Bob and I are going for dinner tomorrow.

Comment: @pyro: Nobody, he is not attending.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: What about the first sentence? `Andy, Bob and his girlfriend Christine, Debby and I are going for dinner tomorrow.`?

Comment: You probably don't realise that there are males named 'Christine'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current punctuation is certainly wrong because *his girlfriend* is undistinguishable from the other items in the enumeration. One solution is to join Bob and Christine:

> Andy, Bob with his girlfriend Christine, Debby, and I are going for dinner tomorrow.

Another is to repeat after the great writers of old and remove the comma after *Christine*:

> Andy, Bob, Christine his girlfriend, Debby, and I are going for dinner tomorrow.

See how William Morris used this in *The Well at the World's End*:

> All these and more knew him and his armour and Falcon his horse, and gave him the sele of the day, and he was nowise troubled at meeting them

**EDIT:** Yet another solution is to avoid all ambiguity by using the name instead of the personal pronoun:

> Andy, Bob, Bob's girlfriend Christine, Debby, and I are going for dinner tomorrow.

The repetition of Bob's name does not sound bad.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I reorder the words: I am going for dinner tomorrow with Andy, Debby, Bob, and his girlfriend Christine.